# Get Column Utilization in DB Tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I was thinking about proper database design while going through some databases where out of 150,000 records some columns had only 5-20 values set. It got me thinking that columns with low utilization should be transferred to a pivot table and was hoping to run a report that would tell me which to evaluate.

I tried a foreach, but it isn't working for me. Any tips?

```
foreach('SELECT table_name,
       column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema = "mydb"', 
'SELECT    ${2}, utilization
FROM      mydb.${1}.${2}
LEFT JOIN
          (
                 SELECT sum(secondary_email)/count(*) AS utilization
                 FROM   (
                               SELECT
                                      CASE
                                             WHEN secondary_email IS NULL THEN 0
                                             ELSE 1
                                      END AS secondary_email
                               FROM   offices ) AS c )
GROUP BY  ${2} ')
```

Comment: What language are you using in the code in your question?

Comment: Mysql for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping for a better answer, feel free to out do me here. Copy and paste the output here and remove the final UNION ALL

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('SELECT ', QUOTE(tb), ', ',QUOTE(col),', sum(`has_value`)/count(*) AS utilization FROM   (SELECT CASE WHEN `',col,'` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS has_value FROM   ',tb,'  ) AS c UNION ALL') SearchSQL
FROM
(
    SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb,column_name col FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'myDB' AND
    (column_type LIKE 'char(%' OR column_type LIKE 'varchar(%' OR column_type LIKE '%text')
) A
```